# Ajax not working in jQuery v1.8.2

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a problem with ajax not working in jQuery v1.8.2 but the alert is working fine.

here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#input" ).click(function(){
        alert('OP');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/medis/pemeriksaan/view_data_obat",
            data: { data: "what you want to pass" },
            dataType: "html", // Note, we tell Ajax to expect HTML back;
            async:true,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#zabita").html();
            },
            error: function(response){
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

HTML code

```
<script src="<?= base_url(); ?>application/views/templates/default/theme/scripts/plugins/system/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  "not working" is not a question, nor does it describe anything.  Can you explain your issue a bit more?

Comment: any error in your dev console?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work? have you checked with firebug or chrome dev tools to see if it actually fires an HTTP Request to the server? if so, what's the result? does the server receive any request? Check all these and tell us more information about exactly what part of the ajax request/response is not working for you.

Comment: P.S. Why are you doing `alert(XMLHttpRequest.response);` in your `error` callback?  You should be printing out the error message that's being sent to you!  Try: `error: function(jqXHR, status, error){ console.log(status); console.log(error); }`  P.S.S. The `error` callback does *not* send you the `response`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#input" ).click(function(){
        alert('OP');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url();?>/medis/pemeriksaan/view_data_obat",
            data: { data: "what you want to pass" },
            dataType: "html", // Note, we tell Ajax to expect HTML back;
            async:true
        }).done(function() {
            alert( "success" );
            $("#zabita").html();
        }).fail(function(response) {
            alert( "error" );
            alert(XMLHttpRequest.response);
        }).always(function() {
            alert( "complete" );
        });
    });
});
```